# Articulation Points Algorithm Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

I have been trying to understand and implement algorithm to find articulation points in a graph in Java, but I am facing problems in implementing the algorithm. Can someone please help me and correct this code?

The code tries to print all the articulation points in a given graph.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Articulation {

    static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> list;
    static boolean[] visited;
    static int[] dfsnumber;
    static int[] lowvalue;
    static int dfscounter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int vertices = s.nextInt();
        int edges = s.nextInt();

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        visited = new boolean[vertices + 1];
        dfsnumber = new int[vertices + 1];
        lowvalue = new int[vertices + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= vertices; i++) {
            list.add(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= edges; i++) {
            int start = s.nextInt();
            int end = s.nextInt();

            list.get(start).add(end);
            list.get(end).add(start);
        }

        Arrays.fill(dfsnumber, -1);

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                dfs(i);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void dfs(int vertex) {
        visited[vertex] = true;
        dfsnumber[vertex] = dfscounter++;
        lowvalue[vertex] = dfsnumber[vertex];

        for (Integer child : list.get(vertex)) {

            if (!visited[child]) {
                visited[child] = true;

                dfs(child);

                lowvalue[vertex] = Math.min(lowvalue[vertex], lowvalue[child]);

                if (lowvalue[child] >= dfsnumber[vertex]) {
                    System.out.println(vertex);
                }

            } else if (!list.get(child).contains(vertex)) {
                lowvalue[vertex] = Math.min(lowvalue[vertex], dfsnumber[child]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Though this code complies and runs but I am not getting the exact correct output i.e. articulation points in the graph.

```
Sample Input : 

4 // number of vertices
3 // number of edges and next few lines follow the (v, u) edge pair.
3 0
0 1
1 2

Sample Output (expected) :

0 1 // articulation points

Sample Input : 
7
8
0 1
1 2
2 0
1 3
1 4
1 6
3 5
4 5

Sample Output (expected):

1

Sample Input : 

5
5
1 0
0 2
2 1
0 3
3 4

Sample Output (expected) :

0 3
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you put sample input and expected output?

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: okay, I know there is some trivial mistake i am making but i can't figure it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.Algorithms.Graphs;

import java.util.*;

public class MattsGraphBook {

    static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> list;
    static boolean[] visited;
    static int[] parent;
    static boolean[] ap;
    static int[] dfsnumber;
    static int[] lowvalue;
    static int dfscounter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int vertices = s.nextInt();
        int edges = s.nextInt();

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        visited = new boolean[vertices + 1];
        parent = new int[vertices + 1];
        ap = new boolean[vertices + 1];
        dfsnumber = new int[vertices + 1];
        lowvalue = new int[vertices + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= vertices; i++) {
            list.add(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= edges; i++) {
            int start = s.nextInt();
            int end = s.nextInt();

            list.get(start).add(end);
            list.get(end).add(start);
        }

        Arrays.fill(dfsnumber, -1);
        Arrays.fill(lowvalue, -1);
        Arrays.fill(parent, -1);
        Arrays.fill(ap, false);
        Arrays.fill(visited, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                dfs(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ap.length; i++) {
            if (ap[i]){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void dfs(int vertex) {
        visited[vertex] = true;
        dfsnumber[vertex] = ++dfscounter;
        lowvalue[vertex] = dfsnumber[vertex];
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.get(vertex).size(); i++) {
            int child = list.get(vertex).get(i);
            if (!visited[child]) {
                c++;
                visited[child] = true;
                parent[child] = vertex;

                dfs(child);

                lowvalue[vertex] = Math.min(lowvalue[vertex], lowvalue[child]);

                if ((lowvalue[child] >= dfsnumber[vertex]) && parent[vertex] != -1) {
                    ap[vertex] = true;
                }
                if ((parent[vertex] == -1) && c > 1) {
                    ap[vertex] = true;
                }

            } else if (child != parent[vertex]) {
                lowvalue[vertex] = Math.min(lowvalue[vertex], dfsnumber[child]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Well finally, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have completed the step from Wikipedia pseudo code [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component)

```
static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> list;
  static boolean[] visited;
  static int[] dfsNumber;
  static int[] lowValue;
  static int[] parent;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int vertices = scanner.nextInt();
    int edges = scanner.nextInt();

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    visited = new boolean[vertices + 1];
    dfsNumber = new int[vertices + 1];
    lowValue = new int[vertices + 1];
    parent = new int[vertices + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= vertices; i++) {
      list.add(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= edges; i++) {
      int v = scanner.nextInt();
      int w = scanner.nextInt();

      list.get(v).add(w);
      list.get(w).add(v);
    }

    Arrays.fill(dfsNumber, -1);
    Arrays.fill(parent, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
      if (!visited[i]) {
        dfs(i, i);
      }
    }
    scanner.close();
  }

  public static void dfs(int i, int vertex) {

    visited[vertex] = true;
    dfsNumber[i] = vertex;
    lowValue[i] = vertex;
    boolean isArticulation = false;
    int childCount = 0;

    for (Integer w : list.get(vertex)) {

      if (!visited[w]) {
        parent[w] = i;
        visited[w] = true;

        dfs(w, w);
        childCount = childCount + 1;
        lowValue[vertex] = Math.min(lowValue[vertex], lowValue[w]);

        if (lowValue[w] >= dfsNumber[vertex]) {
          isArticulation = true;
        }

      } else if (w != parent[i]) {
        lowValue[vertex] = Math.min(lowValue[i], dfsNumber[w]);
      }
    }

    if (parent[i] != -1 && isArticulation || parent[i] == -1 && childCount > 1)
      System.out.println("The output: " + i);
  }
```

Comment: You might wanna recheck,it ain't giving correct output.

Comment: @DeepeshPandey Could you put some test cases and correct outputs

Comment: Added few more test cases.

Comment: @DeepeshPandey , I have updated it and it's working as expected, the output should be outside the for-loop :)

Comment: @DeepeshPandey , It's another answer if you like, could you upvote the solution :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sc0der !

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation so won't be displayed here :P .. I will upvote once I reach 15.